# Disable Screen sharing via the command line in mountain lion

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd, screen-sharing

I want to be able to enable and disable screen sharing from the command line rather than through System Preferences. This is on 10.8.3

To enable screen sharing, I find I only need to change a dictionary value in the following plist:

`/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`

To be precise, to enable screen sharing, I do the following:

`sudo defaults write /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist com.apple.screensharing -dict Disabled -bool false`

And that changes:

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist com.apple.screensharing
{
    Disabled = 1;
}
```

To:

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist com.apple.screensharing
{
    Disabled = 0;
}
```

Fine. I see from this [site](http://pivotallabs.com/enabling-os-x-screen-sharing-from-the-command-line/) that I need to then do this (not sure why):

`sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist`

Now if I want to disable screen sharing I try the reverse:

```
sudo defaults write /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist com.apple.screensharing -dict Disabled -bool true
```

I get:

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist com.apple.screensharing
{
    Disabled = 1;
}
```

Which is good, but then I have no successful way to get launchctl, or whatever (not really sure) to re-read this plist.

I try

`sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist`

and I get:

`nothing found to load`

And indeed, despite the dictionary value for this screen sharing being properly set to indicate screen sharing should be off, well, I still can screen share in just fine.

So what is the proper way to disable screen sharing from the command line on 10.8.3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To start screensharing:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist
```

To stop:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist
```

The `-w` flag modifies the `Disabled` key as appropriate. It's best to let launchctl handle this, as the location where the config files are stored has changed a bit between OS versions.

Comment: how to use this shell Script in Application.