# how to block Adobe, Google and others from installing crap on my Mavericks

Tags: macos, launchd

Adobe and Google insist on install crap on several folders, like update checkers and things like that.

This is the crap I have identified by Adobe.

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist
```

also crap from TeamViewer

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist
```

crap like this run when the system starts and load bloatware on the memory with useless stuff.

I would like to prevent this from happening.

My first idea was to replace the original files with blank ones and set chmod to 000 but when I have to legitimate install some software from them, they replace my file with a new version. The problem is that the installation runs with root privilege.

Is there a way to block my tricky files from being replaced by an installer with root privileges?

I know what you will say... root privileges... but may be there is a way...

Comment: The teamviewer files at least are needed for team viewer so you need to uninstall the whole app. As for Adobe they tend not to be as clear. Also installers will only run with root privileges if you explicitly authenticate them.

Comment: believe me, both work without these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the individual launchd job tickets using the [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) tool:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
```

This will immediately disable the job and the `-w` flag will stop the job from reloading next time you restart.

Given your dislike of these features, please provide feedback to [Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform), [Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en), and [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/createticket.aspx).

See [disable screen sharing via the command line in mountain lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/89567/1860) for alternative approaches for disabling `launchd` managed processes.

Comment: wow, that is fantastic but won't the installers enable their jobs again if I need to run them again? (in case of a update, for example)

Comment: Probably not. The `unload -w` has traditionally been written to a separate override file; rather than the actual job ticket. This may have changed on OS X 10.9, so do test.