# Enable screensharing via SSH and setting password

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop

I am trying to enable VNC (Screen Sharing) on my Mac running OS X Yosemite
I have been able to run this command `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist` ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89565/disable-screen-sharing-via-the-command-line-in-mountain-lion)) to turn VNC on.

The only issue running this command is, it sets a password automatically, in which I do not know what it is, I have to fix it by logging in physically to the computer.

Is there a way how I can enable VNC via SSH and setting the password as the users password?

Comment: Hmm - I never use the VNC password at all. What client are you using to connect to OS X? Perhaps changing that alone would suffice?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to set a VNC password - you might need to also kickstart the ARDAgent, you can use this command instead of just loading the plist:

```
sudo  /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw mypasswd -restart -agent -privs -all
```

The analogous command for using user/password of existing users would be:

```
sudo  /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -configure -allowAccessFor -allUsers -configure -restart -agent -privs -all
```

More detail and discussion at:

[How to enable OS X screen sharing (VNC) through SSH?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30238/)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I am either such at connecting or authentication. The VNC client I am using is 'RealVNC' iOS app. That command enables Remote Management for all users.

Comment: @iProgram Cool - If you want to try out Screens app - it works with the above. I'm hoping someone else has a different solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of Screens app. Only think is it costs £10.99! Not paying that amount for an app! Just trying out stuff with OS X remote settings (VNC Remote Management, SSH etc) to turn them on and off via terminal. :) Not important if I can't do this.

Comment: @iProgram I agree - knowing what a tool is worth is important. For me, using remote sessions across dozens of OS and a handful of devices - that app paid for itself in a week of work. As long as you can trade time for learning - DIY is always fun.

Comment: I still get "TightVNC Viewer: Authentication reason: Authentication or authorization failure" even after running these commands. Is this supposed to be changing the VNC password to my login password?

Comment: @Michael no the commands here simply enable ARD and kickstart the listener. If you need a VNC password different than a log in password, I only know to set that up in the system preference, not from command line.

Comment: ok, i only ask because it wasn't accepting my login password

Comment: Meh, `Warning: macos 10.14 and later only allows control if Screen Sharing is enabled through System Preferences.`